# Removal of parenthesis in Thingsboard telemetry data

Tags: thingsboard

I'm new to MQTT, Dashboards etc.  I'm trying to setup a Dashboard collecting data from a field device.  The published code from my device for a Analog input looks as follows:
{
"devId": "493C220314031120",
"msgType": "aiValueRpt",
"data": {
"AI1": "7481"
},
"timestamp": "1658930342"
}

After Thingsboard receives it, it looks like this:

[telemetry view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPjAs.png)

When added to a dashboard it still shows {"AI1":"7481"} as per following picture
[dashboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsDSh.png)

I would like to process this data so that I only see the actual value (7481 in this case) without the parenthesis as I would also need to use this value for a chart and need a value only.  I'm not sure if I need to use the rule-engine or post-processing of data.  I can only assume that I haven't found an answer to this because it is really basic, but nonetheless I'm hoping for some guidance

Answer (score 0):

You could use the post-processing function for achieving this, but the better approach would be to clean the data before storing it in ThingsBoard.

Via Rule-Chains to you can add a Script Node (Transformation) in the Root Rule Chain, just before Save Timeseries Node. This extracts the desired value out of the data json object:

[image]

```
var msg_new = {};

msg_new["AI1"] = msg.data["AI1"];

return {msg: msg_new, metadata: metadata, msgType: msgType};
```

If you are using ThingsBoard PE there is even a better approach (which I favor) with Integrations and Data Converters. In this case no modification of the rulechains is needed.
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/#how-it-works

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice, I'm going to test the post-processing first and then I'll try the data converter afterwards, I did see it and played around with it, but as mentioned I'm really new to this so need to learn the basics first.  I just wanted this sorted because I'm looking at creating a demo version for which I need it.

Comment: There is also a tutorial for Data Converter and MQTT Broker:  https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/send-data-external-mqtt-brokers/